# Connectivity of the Superior Colliculus

Tags: neuroscience

Does anyone know anything about the connectivity of the superior colliculus? Or know of any straightforward published literature?

I've got that the superficial layers receive input from the visual system and the deep layers have multi-sensory inputs, but I'm finding conflicting information about the specifics.

I've read one source that suggests inputs are from magno and konio cellular retinal ganglion cells. But as I understand it, these are cell types in the lateral geniculate nucleus, so it's not clear if the inputs are from the LGN, or the retina.

Edit: Figure 2  [here, shows "koniocellular" ganglion cells](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123851574011787). Which I can't tell if they're meant to come from the LGN, or retina.

[This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5332863/) discusses some of the connectivity, but only with regards to eye fixation, rather than a general overview.

Comment: Please cite the sources.

Comment: Edited to add a couple of the sources.

Answer (score 1):

(About the tectospinal tract) the tectospinales **fibers originate** in the superior colliculus, its axons pass ventromedially by the central gray matter and cross in the posterior tegmental decussation. The upper colliculus receives visual information, and the tectospinal tract is believed to act as a mediator of reflex eye movements in response to visual stimuli (Neuroanatomy of Crossman and Neary pg 81).

A relatively small number of fibers leave the optic tract, **before** reaching the dorsal nucleus of the lateral geniculate body, to terminate in the pretectal area and superior colliculus (fibers involved in pupillary reflex mediation) (Neuroanatomy of Crossman and Neary pg 157).